# How to use part of sql query in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have this query to get information from two tables:

```
SELECT u.username, u.id,
           SUM(t.result = 1) AS winnings,
           SUM(t.result = 2) AS loses
    FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN tahminler t ON u.id = t.user_id
    GROUP BY u.id
```

I want to get `comments_no` for each user from another table; something like this:

```
SELECT u.username, u.id,
           SUM(t.result = 1) AS winnings,
           SUM(t.result = 2) AS loses,
           f1.comments_no
    FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN tahminler t ON u.id = t.user_id
    INNER JOIN (select count(distinct match_static_id) as comments_no,user_id from comments where user_id = "here is my problem")
    GROUP BY u.id
```

Is it possible to but the value of u.id in the `where user_id = u.id`.
Briefly How to get the comments_no for each user in my query.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a GROUP BY in the sub query:-

```
SELECT u.username, u.id,
           SUM(t.result = 1) AS winnings,
           SUM(t.result = 2) AS loses,
           f1.comments_no
    FROM users u 
    LEFT JOIN tahminler t ON u.id = t.user_id
    INNER JOIN (select user_id, count(distinct match_static_id) as comments_no from comments GROUP BY user_id) f1
    ON u.id = f1.user_id
    GROUP BY u.id
```